# PHP concatenation yielding unexpected results

Tags: php, command-line, concatenation

I am running a very simple PHP script from the command line/server and dynamically creating a variable by concatenating other variables, and then simply printing it out.

my php version on the server is `PHP Version => 5.6.20-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`

Heres my code:

```
$var1 = 'Website-Name';
$var2 = '^8.2.0';
$var3 = 'dev';

$var4 = "composer create-project acquia/lightning-project:" . $var2. " " . $var1. " --no-interaction --stability " . $var3;

echo $var4;
```

when outputted the `$var4` variable is equal to: **--no-interaction --stability**
It doesn't seem to treat the `.` as concatenation and completely ignores everything else including the other string portion.

when I output

```
echo composer create-project acquia/lightning-project:^8.2.0 Website-Name --no-interaction --stability dev;
```

The correct value is shown.
I'm very confused because this is very very basic PHP stuff i've always been good at. this is problematic because this simple task is currently a road block for the functionality of the script, where I should be spending my time.

Anyone have any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: The concatenation works fine: https://3v4l.org/0EEAg

Comment: This code produces "composer create-project acquia/lightning-project:^8.2.0 Website-Name --no-interaction --stability dev" in my console (php 5.6.22 on ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: It's also worked fine for me for 3+ years until today. First issues i've ever had with php concatenation No idea whats going on, looking for any type of insight. I'm thinking it's some sort of server/php issue

Comment: @Alteffour there is absolutely no issue with this code. your problem is elsewhere, but we can't possibly begin troubleshoot something we can't see.

Comment: how/where are you outputting this text?

Comment: just with `echo` for testing. If i use `var_dump` it outputs same thing. Running the script from command line with `php custom_script.php`. If i just concatenate 3 variables only the last variable is preserved as the concatenated variable's value.